# How to merge multiple files into rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I just downloaded the TCGA genomic dataset, which is structured with genomic data files into a folder for each case with a total sample csv file provided for all of the files. The csv is structured in this way:

```
folder_name, file_name
folder1, file1.txt
folder2, file2.txt
folder3, file3.txt
```

And each file is a spreadsheet of the genes stacked vertically in this format:

file_path: folder1/file1.txt

```
geneA, 5
geneB, 2
geneC, 4
```

How can I write a loop to open each file to merge into each row iteratively to get the following format?

```
folder_name, file_name, geneA, geneB, geneC
folder1, file1.txt, 5, 2, 4
folder2, file2.txt, 4, 3, 5
folder3, file3.txt, 6, 2, 4
```

There could be files were one of the genes (eg geneB) is missing, in which case inputting a blank or n/a value could be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Define the root path
ROOT_PATH = 'C:/'  
 
file_info = pd.read_csv('fileinfo.csv')   
file_info.columns = file_info.columns.str.strip()
 
merged_data = pd.DataFrame()
 
for index, row in file_info.iterrows():
    folder_name = row['folder_name'].strip()
    file_name = row['file_name'].strip()
    file_path = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, folder_name, file_name)  # Create the file path
    print(file_path)
     
    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['Gene', f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'])
     
    file_data_transposed = file_data.set_index('Gene').T.reset_index(drop=True)
     
    merged_data = pd.concat([merged_data, file_data_transposed], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
 
merged_data.columns.name = None  # Remove the index name
merged_data.columns = ['geneA', 'geneB', 'geneC']  
 
merged_data['folder_name'] = file_info['folder_name']
merged_data['file_name'] = file_info['file_name']
 
merged_data = merged_data[['folder_name', 'file_name', 'geneA', 'geneB', 'geneC']]
 
print(merged_data)
```

Here is the [kaggle link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/heinzmdsiahaan/notebook8a2b2cfc84)

Comment: Thanks, I used your method but it appears to be slowing down around the 50th item in the loop. Initially, it was building the merged_data at 1 item per second but then slows down to about 1 minute per item. I have 1000 files and each item is 15 mb. Is there a more memory efficient manner to perform this task? I'm worried that it'll slow down further by the last items.

Like would it be more memory efficient to load all 1000 items as objects and then concatenate them?

Comment: @DeepLearner123 this is because this approach merges in a loop, which is inefficient (quadratic behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the folder and file with the os separator, read all unique files and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import os

s = df['folder_name']+os.sep+df['file_name']

tmp = pd.concat({f: pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0, header=None)[1]
                 for f in s.unique()
                 if os.path.exists(f)},
                axis=1).T

out = df.merge(tmp, left_on=s, right_index=True, how='left')

print(out)
```

Output (e.g. with the last file missing):

```
  folder_name  file_name  geneA  geneB  geneC
0     folder1  file1.txt    5.0    2.0    4.0
1     folder2  file2.txt    4.0    3.0    5.0
2     folder3  file3.txt    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

---

##### Debugging the error

Try replacing the `tmp = ...` lines with:

```
d = {}

for f in s.unique():
    if os.path.exists(f):
        try:
            d[f] = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0, header=None)[1]
        except KeyError:
            print(f'"{f}" has an invalid format')
    else:
        print(f'"{f}" not found')

tmp = pd.concat(d, axis=1).T
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the following traceback when running the 4 lines of code on tmp. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\Python\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in <dictcomp>
  File "path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1

Comment: @DeepLearner123 that's unexpected. Which version of pandas did you use? Can you rewrite the dictionary comprehension as a classical loop for testing purposes? (See update)

Comment: Actually, I think I know why. There must be files that don't have two columns. You have to investigate those (see update).