# Breaking up dataframe into chunks for a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a loop ([that was answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77724745/how-to-merge-multiple-files-into-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe)) to iteratively open several csv files, transpose them, and concatenate them into a large dataframe. Each csv file is 15 mb and over 10,000 rows. There are over 1000 files. I am finding that the first 50 loops happen within a few seconds but then each loop takes a minute. I wouldn't mind keeping my computer on overnight but I may need to do this multiple times and I'm worried that it will get exponentially slower. Is there a more memory efficient way to do this such breaking up df into chunks of 50 rows each and then concatenating all of them at the end?

In the following code, df is a dataframe of 1000 rows that has columns to indicate folder and file name.

```
 merged_data = pd.DataFrame()
 count = 0
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = os.path.join(root_path, folder_name, file_name)
    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['Case', f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'], sep='\t')
    file_data_transposed = file_data.set_index('Case').T.reset_index(drop=True)
    file_data_transposed.insert(loc=0, column='folder_file_id', value=str(folder_name+'_'+file_name))
    merged_data = pd.concat([merged_data, file_data_transposed], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: What do you do with `merged_data` once your loop finishes?

Comment: I just save it to a csv after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code is slow is because you are using `concat` in the loop. You should collect the data in a python dictionary then do a single `concat` at the end.

With few improvements:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

root_path = pathlib.Path('root')  # use pathlib instead of os.path

data = {}
# use enumerate rather than create an external counter
for count, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = root_path / folder_name / file_name
    folder_file_id = f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'

    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep='\t',
                            names=['Case', folder_file_id],
                            memory_map=True, low_memory=False)
    data[folder_file_id] = file_data.set_index('Case').squeeze()
    print(count)

merged_data = (pd.concat(data, names=['folder_file_id'])
                 .unstack('Case').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> merged_data
Case       folder_file_id       0       1       2       3       4
0     folderA_file001.txt  1234.0  5678.0  9012.0  3456.0  7890.0
1     folderB_file002.txt  4567.0  8901.0  2345.0  6789.0     NaN
```

Input data:

```
>>> df
   File ID    File Name
0  folderA  file001.txt
1  folderB  file002.txt

>>> cat root/folderA/file001.txt
0   1234
1   5678
2   9012
3   3456
4   7890

>>> cat root/folderB/file002.txt
0   4567
1   8901
2   2345
3   6789
```

Multithreaded version:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

root_path = pathlib.Path('root')


def read_csv(args):
    count, row = args  # expand arguments
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = root_path / folder_name / file_name
    folder_file_id = f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'

    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep='\t',
                            names=['Case', folder_file_id],
                            memory_map=True, low_memory=False)
    print(count)
    return folder_file_id, file_data.set_index('Case').squeeze()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    batch = enumerate(df[['File ID', 'File Name']].to_dict('records'), 1)
    data = executor.map(read_csv, batch)

merged_data = (pd.concat(dict(data), names=['folder_file_id'])
                 .unstack('Case').reset_index())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code worked and is much faster! Just one more thing, I tried to use pd.merge() on the generated dataframe at the end by 'folder_file_id'. However, I ran out of system memory because it is 1 million columns long. Is there a way to merge each row that's generated in the loop by 'folder_file_id' so that each row is merged horizontally while being generated before being concatenated at the end?

Comment: Essentially, I just don't want to get rid of the rest of the row from "df". The data from "df" is not in the final merged dataframe in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a large dataset and want to explore parallelization, you might consider using the `concurrent.futures` module in Python for multi-processing. This way, each process can handle the reading and processing of a subset of your CSV files concurrently.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def process_file(row):
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = os.path.join(root_path, folder_name, file_name)

    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['Case', f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'], sep='\t')
    file_data_transposed = file_data.set_index('Case').T.reset_index(drop=True)
    file_data_transposed.insert(loc=0, column='folder_file_id', value=str(folder_name+'_'+file_name))

    return file_data_transposed

root_path = r'G:\path'

# Adjust the number of processes based on your system's capabilities
num_processes = 4  # You can experiment with different values

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_processes) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(process_file, df.itertuples(index=False)))

merged_data = pd.concat(results, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Don't use multiprocessing when the task is IO-Bounded. In this case, use threading.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if the columns are not valid Python identifiers then the names will be renamed (`_1` for `File_ID`, `_2` for `File Name` and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

check this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

merged_data_list = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = os.path.join(root_path, folder_name, file_name)
    
    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['Case', f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'], sep='\t')
    file_data_transposed = file_data.set_index('Case').T.reset_index(drop=True)
    file_data_transposed.insert(loc=0, column='folder_file_id', value=str(folder_name+'_'+file_name))
    
    merged_data_list.append(file_data_transposed)

# Concatenate all DataFrames in the list at once
merged_data = pd.concat(merged_data_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```