# Include old pandas dataframe after merging

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using this code to generate a dataframe that is merged from many different files. However, the final dataframe doesn't have all the columns of the original dataframe, 'df'. Is there a way to include all the columns of 'df' in the final generated 'merged_data'?

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

root_path = pathlib.Path('root')  # use pathlib instead of os.path

data = {}
# use enumerate rather than create an external counter
for count, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = root_path / folder_name / file_name
    folder_file_id = f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'

    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep='\t',
                            names=['Case', folder_file_id],
                            memory_map=True, low_memory=False)
    data[folder_file_id] = file_data.set_index('Case').squeeze()
    print(count)

merged_data = (pd.concat(data, names=['folder_file_id'])
                 .unstack('Case').reset_index())
```

Comment: read following notice: [mre]

Comment: You say "all the columns" and "all the rows". Which is it, the columns or the rows?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say all the columns in 'df'

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you are overwriting the existing columns in merged data with the columns from the last file you imported. you can include all the columns you want like this:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

root_path = pathlib.Path('root')  # use pathlib instead of os.path

data = {}
# use enumerate rather than create an external counter
for count, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = root_path / folder_name / file_name
    folder_file_id = f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'

    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep='\t',
                            names=['Case', folder_file_id],
                            memory_map=True, low_memory=False)
    data[folder_file_id] = file_data.set_index('Case').squeeze()
    print(count)

# Create a DataFrame with the columns from the original 'df'
df_columns = df[['File ID', 'File Name', ...]]  # Add all columns you want to keep

# Merge the data from files and the columns from the original 'df'
merged_data = (pd.concat([df_columns] + list(data.values()), axis=1)
                 .set_index(['File ID', 'File Name'])
                 .stack().reset_index())

# You can use the above line or the subsequent code if you want to use 'folder_file_id' as an index
# merged_data = (pd.concat([df_columns] + list(data.values()), axis=1)
#                  .set_index('folder_file_id')
#                  .stack().reset_index())
```

add desired columns when you're creating the dataframe with columns from the original df

Answer (score 0):

You have to [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) of `df` index to `merged_data` then use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to concatenate both dataframes:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

root_path = pathlib.Path('root')  # use pathlib instead of os.path

data = {}
# use enumerate rather than create an external counter
for count, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    folder_name = row['File ID'].strip()
    file_name = row['File Name'].strip()
    file_path = root_path / folder_name / file_name
    folder_file_id = f'{folder_name}_{file_name}'

    file_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep='\t',
                            names=['Case', folder_file_id],
                            memory_map=True, low_memory=False)
    data[folder_file_id] = file_data.set_index('Case').squeeze()
    print(count)

merged_data = df.join(pd.concat(data, names=['folder_file_id'])
                        .unstack('Case').set_axis(df.index))
```

Output:

```
>>> merged_data
   File ID    File Name       0       1       2       3       4
0  folderA  file001.txt  1234.0  5678.0  9012.0  3456.0  7890.0
1  folderB  file002.txt  4567.0  8901.0  2345.0  6789.0     NaN
```

Input is the same than [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77735160/15239951):

```
>>> df
   File ID    File Name
0  folderA  file001.txt
1  folderB  file002.txt
```